# jQuery - Multiple different modals, squished into one div (or iframe?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

This webpage serves as the main menu for a game. As the user clicks on different options (load game, open video options, etc), a jQuery UI modal pops up with different contextual options. I don't want to pack all of the modals into the mainmenu.html, because they could be used elsewhere (ie, ingame options menu might bring up video options).

I am thinking a simple div that can be cleared when the user clicks OK or CANCEL. However, when I use get -

```
$('#open-video-options').click(function () {
    $.get('video-menu.html', function (data) {
        $(data).appendTo('#modal');
    });
});
```

On my video menu (trimmed down a bit):

```
<div id="video-options" title="Video Options">
    ...
</div>
<script>
$("#video-options").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        UpdateVideoDisplay();
    },
    buttons: {
        OK: function () {
            ApplyVideoChanges();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
    }
});

$("#modal").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        OK: function () {
            ApplyVideoChanges();
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $(this).empty();
        },
    }
});
UpdateVideoDisplay();
$("#modal").dialog("open");
</script>
```

Upon clicking the video options button, the "#modal" div disappears and a huge chunk of messy DOM appears at the bottom (below everything else):

```
<div class=​"ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable" style="display: none; " tabindex=​"-1" role=​"dialog" aria-describedby=​"video-options" aria-labelledby=​"ui-id-5" >​
```

Is there some way to fix this? Maybe I should use a fullscreen iframe to handle modal objects?